# Is there an adverb for "on working days only"

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, dates

I am writing (yet another) calendar software which should also support recurrent entries/events, i.e. entries that repeat in certain intervals.

So far I have:

- "daily" - happens every day
- "weekly" - happens once every week
- "biweekly" - happens every other week
- "monthly" - happens once per month

Is there any similar short adverb for event that only happen on working days, i.e. days when people are at work/in the office (like Mon-Fri, or Mon-Sat, but not on Sundays)?

Comment: Maybe ask your customers or look at rival software? I suspect you'll have to go with "weekday", a noun often used as an adjective, rather than an adverb ("daily", "weekly", etc, can be adjectives). Although looking at calendar software, most of it seems to avoid the ambiguities of "weekday" by only having options to select the exact days or range of days, not "weekday".

Comment: We have *day* → *daily* and *week* → *weekly*, so it makes logical sense that we should have *weekday* → *weekdaily*. Unfortunately, it hasn't made its way into common use. Or any use that I'm aware of. Without it, all you can say is *every weekday*.

Comment: non-holidays; work days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing you’ll find is “weekday.”  The opposite is, “weekend.”

Comment: So  the adjective would be workdaily (or weekdaily as Jason Bassford suggests) - except that it does not really exist or is at least not in common usage?

Comment: I’d put on the list as “weekdays.”  It doesn’t fit neatly into your list but there isn’t a word that does.  A native English speaker will understand.

Comment: Ok, I think I will go with "weekdays" then, or maybe even "weekdays only".

Answer (score 0):

The word is "[Business days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_day)" for a day of the working week not including official holidays.

(Links go to Wikipedia)